# Syntax Error: Unexpected $q

Tags: mysql

Im getting syntax error, unexpected $q at the $q line..

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT title FROM `PREFIX_GOOGLEMAPZZZ_markers`"
$q = mysql_query($sql)
echo "<select name=\"title\">";
echo "<option size =30 ></option>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['title'] . "'>" . $row['title'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing semicolons at the end of these lines.

```
 $sql = "SELECT title FROM `PREFIX_GOOGLEMAPZZZ_markers`";
 $q = mysql_query($sql);
```